# How to execute this procedure with cx_oracle in Python

Tags: python, procedure, cx-oracle

please, could you help me to execute this procedure in python, I'm having the following error and I can't solve it:

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure up_sia_concilia_sia_sgc (p_cdpais          in     char,
                                                     p_cdconcess       in     char,
                                                     p_cdsite          in     char,
                                                     p_nopraca         in     char,
                                                     p_dtinicial       in     date,
                                                     p_dtfinal         in     date,
                                                     p_arrecadador     in     varchar2,
                                                     p_consulta        in     integer,
                                                     p_nouser          in     number,
                                                     p_tpturno         in     char,
                                                     cs_retorno  in out pc_sia_package.empcurtyp)
as
  lTipos_Pagto     varchar2(4000);
  lTipos_Pagto_SGC varchar2(4000);
  lTipos_Pagto_SIA varchar2(4000);

  l_str_arrec      varchar2(6);
  l_str_pista      varchar2(3);
  l_str_data       varchar2(19);

  lDtUpdate        date;
  lQuery           varchar2(8000);
  lQuery_2         varchar2(8000);
  lquery_3         varchar2(8000);
  lcdtppagto_doacao   tipo_pagto.cdtppagto%type;
  lfltppraca       char(1);

begin
   lcdtppagto_doacao :=  FN_RESGATA_PARAMETRO(p_cdpais,
                                              p_cdconcess,
                                              pc_sca_constantes.c_todas_pracas,
                                              pc_sca_constantes.c_todas_admin,
                                              'TIPO PAGTO DOACAO',
                                              '19');
...
```

Python Code:

```
    out_val = oracle_cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
    retorno_consulta = oracle_cursor.callproc("up_sia_concilia_sia_sgc", ["123", "123", "99", "9999", date.today(), date.today(), "123", 1, 123, "T", out_val])
    print(out_val.getvalue())
```

Error:

```
  File "C:/Users/30-01659/PycharmProjects/DFE/concilicao/rodovias/conciliacao.py", line 746, in gerar_diferenca_conciliacao
    retorno_consulta = oracle_cursor.callproc("up_sia_concilia_sia_sgc", ["123", "123", "99", "9999", date.today(), date.today(), "123", 1, 123, "T", out_val])
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'UP_SIA_CONCILIA_SIA_SGC'
ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I tried several ways and all returned this error, I don't know what else to do

Comment: What is the type of pc_sia_package.empcurtyp?

Comment: I looked in the code, is that it?
TYPE
        EmpCurTyp IS REF CURSOR;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/ref_cursor.py for how to call a procedure that returns a REF CURSOR.